# Restricting SharePoint Lists to one instance of a criteria

Tags: custom-list

I have a SP list that shows multiple instances for each customer (since there are multiple orders for each customer).  I would like to restrict this to one instance per contact or order number.  For example: Customer A has four lines on the list because they have four components of their order.  I want to restrict that to one line on the list.  Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GroupBy feature in the list view to accomplish this.  Make a new view, and group the list data by the field you want to show one grouped value.  This will roll up all of the list data based off of the meta value of the column you choose to group and place it in a single row.